# Select distinct values by key from JSONB column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres v12.0

I have a table

| data |
| --- |
| {"a": "1", "b": "1"} |
| {"a": "2", "b": "1"} |

And I'd like to retrieve a **distinct** list of keys and the **set** of values for each key

| key | values |
| --- | --- |
| a | [ "1", "2" ] |
| b | [ "1" ] |

Not sure how to formulate a query to achieve those results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select key , array_agg(distinct value) 
from table
join lateral (select * from jsonb_each_text(datacolumn)) j on true 
group by key
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a213301c0ce7d1171ca4671f57e81cb)*